# Apache Flink MapState vs Value[Map[String, String]] usage

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I divide stream by key, and manage a map state for each key like;

```
stream
  .keyBy(_.userId)
  .process(new MyStateFunc)
```

Every time, I have to read all values under a key, calculate something and update only a few of them. An example;

```
class MyStateFunc() .. {
  

    val state = ValueState[Map[String, String]]

    def process(event: MyModel...): {
       val stateAsMap = state.value()
       val updatedStateValues = updateAFewColumnsOfStateValByUsingIncomingEvent(event, stateAsMap)
       doCalculationByUsingSomeValuesOfState(updatedStateValues)
       state.update(updatedStateValues)
    }
    def updateAFewColumnsOfStateValByUsingIncomingEvent(event, state): Map[String, String] = {
      val updateState = Map.empty
      event.foreach {case (status, newValue) => 
        updateState.put(status, newValue)
      }
      state ++ updatedState
    }
    def doCalculationByUsingSomeValuesOfState(stateValues): Map[String, String] = {
      // do some staff by using some key and values
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way. Yeah, I have to read all the values (at least some of them) to do a calculation, but I also need to update a few of them, not all of the Map stored in each key. I'm just wondering that which one is more efficient; `Value[Map[String, String]]` vs `MapState[String, String]`?

If I use `MapState[String, String]`, I have to do something like below in order to update related keys;

```
    val state = MapState[String, String]
    def process(event: MyModel...): {
       val stateAsMap = state.entries().asScala
       event.foreach { case (status, newValue)
         state.put(status, newValue)
       }
    }
```

I'm not sure trying to update state for each event type is the efficient or not.

```
mapState.putAll(changeEvents)
```

Will this only overwrite related keys instead of all of them?

Or can be another way to overcome?

Answer (score 1):

If your state only has a few entries, then it likely doesn't matter much. If your map can have a significant number of entries, then using `MapState` (with RocksDB state backend) should significantly cut down on the serialization cost, as you're only updating a few entries versus the entire state.

Note that for efficiency you should iterate over the `MapState` once, doing your calculation and (occasionally) updating the entry, assuming that's possible.